# Delete and shift pixels with PAINT.NET or other tool

Tags: gimp, crop, paint.net, image-manipulation

How can I delete and shift pixels with PAINT.NET ?

That is if I delete an entire vertical or horizontal slice of the image, how can I just have the remainder slide over and the image size automatically sized to what's left over?

If not with PAINT.NET is this effect possible with anything else? Gimp perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick has a [`-chop` operation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#chop).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete a horizontal slice from the image and move up the lower part of the image (that is under the removed slice), you don't really need to delete that slice at all.
Simply select Select tool (press S) then select that "lower" part from the image you want to retain and be moved up, then change to Move tool (V) and move the selection up with Ctrl+Up, the selected (and moved) image part will cover the "slice".

You can move the selected part with the mouse but that is unstable as you cannot lock the movement to only Y axis.

Finally crop the image to the proper size.

This will also work if the would-be-deleted slice is on the edge of the picture, although a single canvas resize will do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Paint.net has a "Canvas Resize" function under the Image menu that I believe will do exactly what you are describing, as long as you are wanting to slice away the edges of the image.

Check under the Image menu for the Canvas Resize.